# Constructing a tautology from a simple equation $x = 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a simple equation/statement

$x=5$

I multiply left hand side by 5 and right hand side by $x$. I can do that since they are equal as can be seen in the initial statement.

I thus obtain

$x\cdot5=5\cdot x$

which is a tautology (or an equation for which every $x$ is a solution).

Unlike many similar manipulations where people "prove" stuff like $1=2$ (which usually arises through division by 0), in my case I don't see anything illegal in my manipulations.

Why is it that an equation with one solution $x=5$ turns into tautology for all $x$ through seemingly legal manipulations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x=5$ then $x\cdot 5 = 5 \cdot x$ is a reasonable deduction. As you say, the second statement is true for any $x$, so it is certainly true when $x=5$.

But you can't go the other way. It doesn't follow from $x\cdot 5 = 5 \cdot x$ that $x=5$. You can't divide one side by $x$ and the other by $5$ and maintain equality unless $x=5$, but that means assuming what you wanted to show.

The fact that the implication goes one way but not the other simply means that the two statements are not equivalent - which probably seems obvious when put like that.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So in other words, the manipulation which changes $x=5$ to $x\cdot5=5\cdot x$ is not "equivalence-preserving" in the way in which addition of 2 preserves equivalence in $x-2=4$ and $x=6$? Therefore, it is incorrect to produce $x\cdot5=5\cdot x$ from $x=5$ while at the same time expecting the two to have identical solution sets?

Comment: @Rokas You applied 2 different operations in those examples, addition does the same $x=6 \implies x+6=6+x$.

Answer (score 1):

Because whereas $x=5$  →  $5x=x5$, the opposite direction is simply not true.

So,in your words"which is tautology or an equation for which every x is a solution.." It is either an equation,or a tautology..

Comment: Well,I am not a specialist in logic by any account but I think that if it is viewed as an equation,it is one that holds for every $x$.But still,the paradox is formed by trying to prove what you assume is correct(the statement that x=5).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (Still getting used to the comments system here.)